# If $AB = -BA$, then tr$(A) = $ tr$(B) = 0 $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

If $A, B$ are invertible matrices such that $AB = -BA$ ( which implies tr$(AB) =$ tr$(-BA)$), then show that tr$(A) = $ tr$(B) = 0$.

My attempt: I could only show that tr$(AB) = 0$.

Comment: I have mentioned that $A, B$ are invertible

Comment: Please be more clear about your assumptions, which are differ in the title and body of your post. Do you just want $tr(AB)=tr(-BA)$, or do you require $AB=-BA$?

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh are we given that $AB = -BA$, or do we merely know that $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = -\operatorname{tr}(BA)$? The title of your question contradicts the body.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry I meant AB = -BA and trace part is the consequnce of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use invertibility and invariance of the trace, indeed the eigenvalues, under conjugation (change of basis): 
$$
A=-BAB^{-1}
$$
so 
$$
\text{tr}(A)=-\text{tr}(BAB^{-1})=-\text{tr}(A)\implies \text{tr}(A)=0
$$
and identically for $B$.

Comment: The problem is that it does not follow from the assumption on traces that $A=-BAB^{-1}$, I think...

Comment: @paulgarrett in the title, op seems to assume that $AB=-BA$. I see now where the confusion arose

Comment: @paulgarrett you have answered the question in the body, where as qbert was looking at the question in the title

Comment: Indeed, I see now...

Answer (score 3):

Your surmise is correct: it is not generally true that both traces of $A$ and $B$ are $0$.

For real matrices $A,B$, ${\mathrm tr}(AB)$ is an inner product on $n$-by-$n$ matrices, so saying that is $0$ is merely an orthogonality relation. It does not imply orthogonality to the identity matrix, in general! :)

For example, ${\mathrm tr}\pmatrix{1&0\cr 0&1}\pmatrix{0&1\cr 1&0}=0$, meaning that these two matrices are orthogonal to each other with respect to that inner product, but certainly the first is not orthogonal to the identity (since it is the identity).

EDIT: note that if the trace of both $AB$ and $BA$ are $0$, then the one is the negative of the other.

EDIT-EDIT: I haven't carefully kept track, but the other answers seem to be answering a slightly different question, namely, with the assumption that $AB=-BA$. But the question as I've read it only assumes something about *traces*. ?

EDIT-EDIT-EDIT: the question title and body do not match...

Comment: the matrices are invertible

Comment: @qbert, yes, both the identity matrix and the anti-diagonal matrix are invertible...

Comment: @paulgarrett in your new example, we don't have $AB = -BA$

Comment: of course that was not there when I posted my comment. See @Omnomnomnom comment

Comment: +1 for the other  reasonable interpretation of the ambiguous question and the inner product interepretation

Comment: @paulgarrett My bad, I actually meant AB = -BA and tr(AB) = -tr(BA) follows as a consequence.

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh then the result has the benefit of being true and my or omnomnomnom's answer's works

Answer (score 2):

Since the matrices are invertible, we note (by multiplying on the right by $B^{-1}$) that $A = -BAB^{-1}$ and hence
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A) = -\operatorname{tr}(BAB^{-1})
$$
However, since we also have $\operatorname{tr}(A) = \operatorname{tr}(BAB^{-1})$, we conclude that $\operatorname{tr}(A) = 0$.

Symmetrically, conclude that $B$ has trace $0$.

Comment: I don't see why $A=-BAB^{-1}$ from the assumption on traces...

Comment: @paulgarrett see the title

Comment: Ah, yes, and/but the title is different from the body... Two different questions.